# Transport Unavailable for OAuth

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire, google-oauth

I am trying to login with google into my firebase project and I am getting a transport unavailable error with both the popup and redirect functions from firebase. Is it because I am working locally or am I doing something wrong here?

```
var app = angular.module('WOM', ["firebase"]);
app.controller('SampleCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebaseObject', '$firebaseAuth', function($scope, $firebaseObject, $firebaseAuth){
var ref = new Firebase('https://who-owes-me.firebaseio.com/'); //Where data is stored
var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);

$scope.login = function() {
    $scope.authData = null;
    $scope.error = null;

    auth.$authWithOAuthPopup("google").then(function(authData){
        $scope.authData = authData;
    }).catch(function(error){
        $scope.error = error;
    });
}

$scope.data = $firebaseObject(ref); //assign data to scope

$scope.data.$loaded()
    .then(function(){
        console.log($scope.data);
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.error(err);
    })
}]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This likely means that you're working off the file system.**

In order to run Auth methods, you'll have to be working on a bona-fide server. It's a good practice in general to develop off of a local server rather than the file system as that's closer to what the production environment behave like.

[Try the `http-server` npm module to get up and running quickly.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)

Comment: awesome! Thanks David

Comment: An alternative to `http-server` is to use the Firebase CLI's `firebase serve` command.

Comment: @david-east I have an angular app hosted in firebase and it runs good in browsers. But I created an iOS webview app for it. And I'm getting TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE when trying to log with facebook when using the iOS app. Any ideas?

Comment: @John actually i did. Give me a few hours and i will come up with an answer in this topic describing my solution.

Comment: @John Take a look at my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same problem when developing an angular app hosted in firebase.

It was running good in browsers but when opening it in an iOS webview app it started getting TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE when trying to login with facebook.

First I got into the firebase documentation for [Dealing with Popups and Redirects](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-popups) and this took me into `authWithOAuthRedirect` but it wasn't working either.

After this I discovered that I was using a [firebase version with a known issue](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/changelog.html) regarding `authWithOAuthRedirect` that was solved on version 2.4.1. **So make sure you are using version 2.4.2 or migrate your app to firebase 3.0**.

I was still running into another problems and after a little more research on this I started using the `onAuth` together with my authentications. `onAuth` is called every time your users successfully authenticate. It makes everything a lot more easier.

So my login controller is now looking as follows:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', 'Auth', 'fbutil', 'FBURL', function($scope, Auth, fbutil, FBURL) {

    var ref = new Firebase(FBURL);
    ref.onAuth( function(authData){
      if (authData){
        //User authenticated. Do your logic.
      }
    });

    $scope.fbLogin = function() {
      ref.authWithOAuthPopup("facebook", function(error, authData) {
          if (error){
            if (error.code === "TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE") {
              Auth.$authWithOAuthRedirect("facebook", function(error) {
                console.log(error);
              });
            }
            $scope.err = errMessage(error);
          }
      });
    };
})
```